# Salt-minions service consuming over 100% CPU on ubuntu, cannot remove it or find how its restarting

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, salt-stack

We used to use salt-master to manage about 10 servers, but have stopped now.

One of the servers is now constantly running a salt-minions service which consumes around 140%-160% of the CPU all the time. I kill it, and it just comes back again and again.

I have used apt-get to remove and purge any packages that include salt-*, as well as used dpkg to do the same.. The master salt server is not running. Yet, this instance just keeps smashing itself with this random process that just won't die.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

[Screenshot of running processes and output from apt-get packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW5zy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be CVE related, and you need to rebuild/redeploy these systems.

Please read both:

- [SaltStack Blog: Critical Vulnerabilities Update CVE-2020-11651 and CVE-2020-11652](https://community.saltstack.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-update-cve-2020-11651-and-cve-2020-11652/)
- [saltexploit.com](https://saltexploit.com)

Snippet from the CVE blog:

> *...a critical vulnerability was discovered affecting Salt Master versions 2019.2.3 and 3000.1 and earlier. SaltStack customers and Salt users who have followed fundamental internet security guidelines and best practices are not affected by this vulnerability. The vulnerability is easily exploitable if a Salt Master is exposed to the open internet.*
>
> *As always, please follow our guidance and secure your Salt infrastructure with the best practices found in this guide: See: [Hardening your Salt Environment](http://em.saltstack.com/v07N0f3J0h9QPv41H01Q000).*
>
> *This vulnerability has been rated as critical with a Common Vulnerability Scoring System (CVSS) score of 10.0.*

Snippet from saltexploit:

> **This was a crypto-mining operation**
>
> - salt minions are affected and as of version 5, masters may be as well
> - `salt-minions` is a [compiled xmrig binary](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig).
> - `salt-store` contains a RAT, [nspps](https://ironnet.com/blog/malware-analysis-nspps-a-go-rat-backdoor/), which **continues to evolve and become more nasty**
> - Atlassian confirms the newer revisions of the binary are a version of [h2miner](https://www.lacework.com/h2miner-botnet/)
>
>   - [Additional information](https://analyze.intezer.com/#/analyses/2939aa77-6c19-47e0-926a-ab26ec4efbf6)
> - As a RAT, salt-store is more concerning than salt-minions. More on that later
> - There have been at least 5 different versions of the salt-store payload, each more advanced than the last.
> - There are additional backdoors installed, and private keys are getting stolen right and left
>
> Seriously, change out your keys!
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> - very high CPU usage, sometimes only on 1 core, sometimes on all
> - Fan spin! (Physical hardware only, of course.)
> - Mysterious process named `salt-minions` is CPU intensive, stemming from `/tmp/salt-minions` or `/usr/bin/`
>     additional binary in `/var/tmp/` or `/usr/bin` named `salt-store` or `salt-storer`
> - Firewalls disabled
> - Most applications crashing or taken offline

**Your screenshots have shown `salt-minions` named processes, and high CPU usage, just as described.**

It would be a good idea to join the Salt community slack, too: [SaltStack Community Slack](https://saltstackcommunity.herokuapp.com) and take a look at both the `#salt-store-miner-public` and `#security` channels.

Answer (score 0):

Check your root's crontab with:

```
sudo crontab -u root -l
```

If you see a wget/curl download of a shell script from a random ip, you got the miner.
How to fix it:

Plan A:

0. Update salt-server
1. Wipe and reinstall all the servers connected to that master.

Plan B (usually more feasible)

0. Update salt-server and minions
1. delete the crontab with `sudo crontab -u root -e`
2. kill the salt-store and the salt minion process with `kill -9 <pid> <pid>` (get the pids with `ps faxu`)
3. delete the salt minion fake executable, usually in /tmp/